# Как отключить кэширование статических файлов(css) django cpanel

Tags: python, html, css, django

У меня такая проблема: Каждый раз когда вношу изменения на css файл на cpanel и перезапускаю приложение нету изменений(со стороны дизайна) на сайте, он остается таким же каким был. Только при shift+F5 страница изменяется. А мне нужно чтобы это было без принудительной перезагрузки при обычной перезагрузке страницы

views.py

```
@login_required
@cache_control(max_age=0, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True)
def index(request):
    users = ForumUser.objects.all().order_by('date_joined')
    posts = Posts.objects.all().order_by('-date')

    context = {
        'users': users,
        'posts': posts
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

Таким образом я пробовал отключить кеширование, на локальном сервере получилось, но в cpanel нет

Я еще пробовал изменять версии css тоже не сработало

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>
```

Попробовав изменить .htaccess тоже не дало никаких результатов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такая фича **get** параметр, чтоб у пользователей обновлялись изменения *(так как отключать кеш - не есть хорошо)*.

Просто меняете ссылку css файла скажем с **style.css** на **style.css?v=1.0.0.1**

И в последующих модификациях css/js -- просто меняйте сам индекс **get** параметра

Comment: да,я уже решил и забыл закрыть, спасибо что еще раз подтвердили мое решение